# $P(B|\{X=i\}) = a$ equivalent to $X=i⟹P(B)=a$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, markov-chains

> Question: Let $X$ be a random variable then is the statement $\mathbb{P}(B|\{X=i\})$ = 0.6(random number), equivalent of saying: $X = i \implies \mathbb{P}(B) = 0.6$?

> Also say in the case A and B are conditionally independent if we condition on the event $\{ X = i \}$, which is $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B|\{ X = i \}) =\mathbb{P}(A|\{ X = i \}\mathbb{P}(B|\{ X = i\})$. Is it equivalent to:
> $X = i \implies \mathbb{P}(A\cap B) =\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)?$

I don't know what conditional probability means from a measure theory perspective, but I was taught in undergraduate probably that $\mathbb{P}(A|B)$ where A and B are events is defined as $\frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}$. However, treating it as such a definition is somewhat weird when I write proofs with regard to Markov chains, so can I just treat it as the first order logic implication as above?

If I can, I also wonder if it is possible to write it in this first order logic form for some events B, $\mathbb{P}(A|B)$, where B does not come from a preimage of what a random variable.

Comment: I think if you read a measure theory text, it will clear it up. In such texts, the author actually constructs a Markov Chain. Conditioning is viewed as a way to construct new random variables in this context.

Comment: To be precise, one thinks of the space $(S,\mathcal S)$. Let $p: S\times \mathcal S \to [0,1]$ be a Markov kernel, meaning $x\mapsto p(x,A)$ is measurable and $A\mapsto p(x,A)$ is a probability measure. Then given sets and an initial measure $\mu$ on $(S,\mathcal S)$ and sets $B_1,\dots,B_{n+1}$, one defines $$P(X_n \in B_n,\dots,X_1\in B_1,X_0\in B_0) = \int_{B_0}\mu(dx_0)\int_{B_1}p(x_0,dx_1)\cdots \int_{B_n}p(x_{n-1},dx_n)$$

Comment: Then use Kolmogorov consistency theorem to get a probability measure $P_{\mu}$ on $(S^{\mathbb N},\mathcal B(\mathcal S^{\mathbb N}))$. One can then show that under this construction that $P_{\mu}(X_{n+1}\in B \mid X_0,X_1,\dots,X_n) = p(X_n,B)$. This is the presentation given by Durrett in his book PTE

Comment: And yes, I think this is an okay way to think of it, at least in the context of Markov chains. But you should really write it like this. $$P_{\mu}(B \mid X_0 = x) = P_x(B)$$ where $\{P_x\}_{x}$ is a family of probability measures on the markov chain, and $x$ denotes the initial condition of the chain.

Comment: Short answer, up to my understanding, is "yes". It is for me a good way to rhink about it.

Comment: I disagree with Thomas. The short answer is a definite "no". Slightly longer answer: This is not how the formalism of probability theory works. $\mathbb{P}(B)$ is fixed once the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ is fixed. Using such logical implications is not valid. If you want to condition on events, use MUST use conditional probability, which is what this concept was introduced for.

Comment: Thanks for the disagreement :). But the intuitive idea these frameworks are formalizing is exaclty the one written behind the expressions of the OP. For example in the first case the expressions reads "given that X=i happened, the probability that B=a is equal to 0.6". The condition is just taking the subpopulation of all events where X=i. Apart from the different notation that should be used to formalize, I read in these expressions the right intuitive concept. My point of view at the moment at least..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would have said something like:

"Based on the info that random variable $X$ has taken value $i$ we conclude that the probability of occurrence of event $B$ is now $0.6$"

then I would agree, so IMV the intuition on this is okay.

But I disagree with using a logical implication for that. Firstly its premisse is false (because $X$ is a function and $i$ is not) so that the implication is always true no matter what is implied.

If you repair this by taking something like $X(\omega)=i$ then still things are not okay because $\mathbb P(B)$ is a *fixed* real number not depending on $\omega$ or $i$.

Let's just do it without that implication. Our intuition does not really need it.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(B|A)=k\tag1$$ $$A \text{ happens}\implies P(B)=k\tag2$$

It is false that for every pair of events $A$ and $B$ and every $k\in[0,1],$ statements $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent.

A counterexample is a toss of a fair coin, with $A$ and $B$ being the event of a head and of a tail, respectively, and with $k$ being $0.5;$ here, statement $(1)$ is false while statement $(2)$ is true.

---

**Addendum**

> OP: Could you elaborate on the counterexample? I don't really understand what you mean.

When you plug the counterexample into equation $(1),$ LHS $=0\ne$ RHS, so statement $(1)$ is False; when you plug the counterexample into implication $(2),$ its consequent(conclusion) is True, so, regardless of its antecedent(premise)'s truth value, statement $(2)$ is True.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the counterexample? I don't really understand what you mean

Comment: I see what you mean now. Thank you!